# How can I set a date based off a variable?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a calendar event based off the contents of a variable.

```
var data = ws.getRange(2, 2, lr-1, 8).getValues();

  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

  var datax = data[I];

  var dt = datax[7];

  var dtdate = Utilities.formatDate(dt, "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")

  var etitle = datax[1] + " " + "exclusion";

  var start = new Date(dtdate);
  var end = new Date(dtdate);

  var newevent = calendar.createEvent(etitle, start, end)
```

...from the above snippet you can see that I am trying to initialise the variables "start" and "end" as the variable dtdate. Im basically trying to say "Create an event on each date in the column"

Can anyone help point out where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [mcve]. Specifically, Describe the problem section .

Answer (score 1):

### If you log `start`, it will return `Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 1970`

The problem is the way you formatted the date.

Provided that `dt` is a valid date object, defining

`var start = new Date(dt);
 var end = new Date(dt);`

will allow you to create the event as intended - no need to format the date into a string object.

> Also: Apps Script is case sensitive, `I` is not the same like `i`